# Looping a Sound in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to create an application that plays a sound repeatedly at a regular interval. I've tried using the in onTick method for the CountdownTimer class and then using a  MediaPlayer object to play the sound. This works for moderately slow rates of repeation (1 sound per second) but anything faster than that and the program doesn't work properly. I suspected that the issue was the length of the media file I used, but shortening it didn't seem to do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool).

Comment: @greeble31 Seems to be working just fine now, thanks for the help!